# How to get the value of td using jquery that has textboxes in second row only

Tags: html, jquery

I have this grid. The html is given below. It has textboxes in the second row while there are simple empty tds in the first row. Now I am trying to save the values in textboxes using juqery but it just gives me undefined .Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<table id='export_history_table' class='display' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style=' width: 100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='20%' class='Greyheader'>3.1 Business</th>
      <th width='10%' class='Greyheader'>2015</th>
      <th width='20%' class='Greyheader'>2016</th>
      <th width='25%' class='Greyheader'>2017</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr pkid=''>
      <td class='GreyBorder'>Export Business with AKBL</td>
      <td class='GreyBorder'></td>
      <td class='GreyBorder'></td>
      <td class='GreyBorder'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr pkid=''>
      <td class='GreyBorder'>Export Buisness with Other Banks</td>
      <td class='GreyBorder ExportHistory'>
        <input type='text' style='text-align:left; width: 95%' class='mediumTextField' value='' onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumeric(event,this);" />
      </td>
      <td class='GreyBorder ExportHistory'>
        <input type='text' style='text-align:left; width: 95%' class='mediumTextField' value='' onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumeric(event,this);" />
      </td>
      <td class='GreyBorder ExportHistory'>
        <input type='text' style='text-align:left; width: 95%' class='mediumTextField' value='' onkeypress="return 
         onlyAlphaNumeric(event,this);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I am saving the values entered in textboxes

```
   $('#export_history_table tbody tr').each(function () {

                 ExportHistoryList += $(this).attr('pkid') + "~";
                 ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val() + "~";
                 ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(2)').find('input').val() + "~";
                 ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').find('input').val() + "~";

            
         });
```

I have tried various other ways but in vain.  Please help.

Comment: When/where is the code you've provided?  In an event? Which event?  in doc.ready?  What do you do with `ExportHistoryList` once it's set?

Comment: @freedomn-m I will pass this ExportHistory List to my class but I just need to get the value of tds. I am getting undefined .

Comment: You don't have 7 columns in your sample table.  Assuming you do, you'd want to skip the first row as it doesn't have any inputs, so if your table has only 1 row of inputs, there's no need to use `$("tr").each` so change that to `var tr = $("#export_history_table tbody tr").eq(1);  ExportHistoryList += tr.attr("pkid")` etc

Comment: @freedomn-m yes sorry there will be only three columns. I need to access my second tr and the find the textboxes value of those since I  do not have  any text boxes in my first tr

Comment: Right, so: `var tr = $("#export_history_table tbody tr").eq(1);  ExportHistoryList += tr.attr("pkid") ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m will this apply looping? you mean to say '' $('#export_history_table tbody tr').eq(1)() {''

Comment: If you only have 1 row, why do you want to loop?  So not, not in the conventional sense

Answer (score 0):

the `undefined` came form first row that has no `input`, you need to check if the `td` has `input`. and you can simplified the selector `.find('td:eq(1)').find('input')` to `.find('td:eq(1) input')`

```
$('#export_history_table tbody tr').each(function () {
  if(!$(this).find('td:eq(1) input').length); // add this check
    return

  ExportHistoryList += $(this).attr('pkid') + '~';
  ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(1) input').val() + '~';
  ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(2) input').val() + '~';
  ExportHistoryList += $(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val() + '~';
});
```

as comment below `:eq` is deprecated you can change it with

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(1) input').val()
// or 
$(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input').val() // 0 mean first element
```

Comment: Note that `:eq` is deprecated: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/